# Meaning of "with" statement without "as" keyword

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm familiar with using python's `with` statement as a means of ensuring finalization of an object in the event of an exception being thrown.  This usually looks like

```
with file.open('myfile.txt') as f:
    do stuff...
```

which is short-hand for

```
f = file.open('myfile.txt'):
try:
    do stuff...
finally:
    f.close()
```

or whatever other finalization routine a class may present.

I recently came across a piece of code dealing with OpenGL that presented this:

```
with self.shader:
    (Many OpenGL commands)
```

Note that absence of any `as` keyword.  Does this indicate that the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of the class are still to be called, but that the object is never explicitly used in the block (i.e., it works through globals or implicit references)?  Or is there some other meaning that is eluding me?

Comment: If you don't need to alias the context manager inside the `with` block, that's fine - see also e.g. [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress). Strictly, you could do `with open(...): ...`, although as you then can't access the file handler there isn't much point!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The context manager can **optionally** return an object, to be assigned to the identifier named by `as`. And it is the object returned by the `__enter__` method that is assigned by `as`, not necessarily the context manager itself.

Using `as <identifier>` helps when you create a *new* object, like the `open()` call does, but not all context managers are created just for the context. They can be reusable and have already been created, for example.

Take a *database connection*. You create the database connection just once, but many database adapters let you use the connection as a context manager; enter the context and a transaction is started, exit it and the transaction is either committed (on success), or rolled back (when there is an exception):

```
with db_connection:
    # do something to the database
```

No new objects need to be created here, the context is entered with `db_connection.__enter__()` and exited again with `db_connection.__exit__()`, but we already *have* a reference to the connection object.

Now, it *could* be that the connection object produces a cursor object when you enter. Now it makes sense to assign that cursor object in a local name:

```
with db_connection as cursor:
    # use cursor to make changes to the database
```

`db_connection` still wasn't called here, it already existed before, and we already have a reference to it. But whatever `db_connection.__enter__()` produced is now assigned to `cursor` and can be used from there on out.

This is what happens with file objects; `open()` returns a file object, and `fileobject.__enter__()` returns the file object *itself*, so you can use the `open()` call in a `with` statement *and* assign a reference to the newly created object in one step, rather than two. Without that little trick, you'd have to use:

```
f = open('myfile.txt')
with f:
    # use `f` in the block
```

Applying all this to your shader example; you already have a reference to `self.shader`. It is quite probable that `self.shader.__enter__()` returns a reference to `self.shader` again, but since you already have a perfectly serviceable reference, why create a new local for that?

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is nicely put.

The only thing I kept asking myself while reading it, is where is the confirmation of the following scenario.   In the event there is an assignment in the body of the context of the with statement, anything on the right side of the assignment is first "bound" to the context. So, in the following:

```py
with db_connection():
   result = select(...)
```

... `select` is ~ `ref_to_connection.select(...)`

I put this here for anyone like me who comes and goes between languages and might benefit by a quick reminder of how to read and track the refs here.