# Why variable is optional in a with statement?

Tags: python, with-statement

I learnt recently the 'with' statement in python and its usage, mainly from the article [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) and the [official documentation for with statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

The most used example is understandable for me

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data
```

ok so we open the file `x.txt`, we perform some tasks with it and it is automatically closed. The `f` variable is used to read in the file and do other tasks.

But in the official documentation, the target variable after the expression is optional:

```
with_stmt ::=  "with" with_item ("," with_item)* ":" suite
with_item ::=  expression ["as" target]
```

I didn't find any example of with statement used without a target variable. Is there cases where this variable is not necessary?

Comment: multiprocessing.Lock is an example http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Comment: Anecdote: I once wrote a `with silenced_output():` statement, which redirected all `stdout` messages to dev/null. `with silenced_output() as x:` wouldn't make much sense, because I didn't need to do anything with x.

Comment: See also [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress).

Comment: Ok, I didn't noticed that this question have already been answerd [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26342829/1887976). Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are, you can find a couple of them in this answer :   [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for)

The most straightforward I can think of is the thread lock (also listed in the previous link):

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    # Critical section of code
```

For the record I'd also quote [the `with` doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) :

> The with statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with methods [...]. This allows common try...except...finally usage patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.

As you don't always need a variable in `try...except...finally`, you do not absolutely need a target variable in a `with` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
from threading import Lock

lock = Lock()

with lock:
    # access critical data

# continue
```

hope it helps.