# Difference on context manager with and without "as" clause

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

First, I need to apologize because I'm not able to provide a clear [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for my question yet.  My question is about a strange phenomenon I encountered deep in a code base and I would like to understand how this can happen, so in a way I'm asking how I can *create* the MCVE for this phenomenon in the first place.

## tl;dr

How can it be that it matters whether or not an `as` clause is used in a `with` statement where the assigned variable isn't used at all?

## Longer Version

We are using Airflow (the Apache project), and in there a class called `DAG` exists.  This class is supposed to be used as a context manager for `with` clauses like this:

```
with DAG(**some_parameters) as dag:
    do_something_with(dag)
```

This works as expected.

However, in some cases we do not use the `dag` variable in the `with` clause, and therefore IDEs warn, and next to renaming it to `_dag` instead (to declare the non-usage), I tried removing the `as dag` clause completely:

```
with DAG(**some_parameters):
    do_something_without_passing_dag()
```

To my understanding of Python this should be equivalent to the version with the `as dag` clause at runtime:

```
with DAG(**some_parameters) as dag:
    do_something_without_passing_dag()
```

But, surprisingly, in the context of the Airflow project, there seems to be a difference between the two.  With the `as dag` clause the code works as expected; without the `as dag` clause, an error is shown (see at the end of this post).  Distressingly, this error appears in the log of the Airflow process and does not contain references to my code at all.

I need to point out that in the Airflow context, these `with` statements are on the toplevel of a small module, **so the `as` statement creates a module-global variable** if present.  I don't know if this is relevant.  If so, I don't understand why.

To my understanding, it should *never* make any difference whether I'm providing an `as` clause or not if I do not use the variable at all.  Here it seems to be the case nevertheless.

I already investigated three aspects:

1. I monitored the input and output of the `__enter__()` method of the `DAG` class.  In both cases both input (arguments) and output (return value) were the same (return value was a context manager object of course).  So here there didn't seem to be any difference based on the existence of the `as` clause.
2. When using the `as` clause, in the `with` clause I deleted the variable (`del dag`) as a first statement.  Then this version behaved like the version without the `as` clause, i. e. it raised an error.
3. I looked at the [source of the DAG](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py) and found that in its [`__enter__()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L348), it stores the current context object in a [`DagContext` class](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L1712), and the `do_something_without_passing_dag()` can ([and will](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L409)) access the `DAG` object from the `DagContext`.  But since this all is independent from the variable created with the `as` statement, I don't see how this could matter.

**Can anybody provide an explanation on why this can be the case?**

Here the error stack trace I can find in the Airflow log:

```
webserver_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
webserver_1  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
webserver_1  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
webserver_1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
webserver_1  |     raise value
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
webserver_1  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
webserver_1  |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
webserver_1  |     return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
webserver_1  |     return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 258, in decorated_view
webserver_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 281, in wrapper
webserver_1  |     return f(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
webserver_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1958, in paused
webserver_1  |     models.DagModel.get_dagmodel(dag_id).set_is_paused(is_paused=is_paused)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
webserver_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1562, in set_is_paused
webserver_1  |     subdags = self.get_dag().subdags
webserver_1  | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'subdags'
```

Comment: does it have to be literally `as dag` or can it also be `as XYZ`?

Comment: The name of the variable doesn't seem to matter.  `as a` also works, so does `as XYZ`.

Comment: did you have a look at ["Meaning of “with” statement without “as” keyword"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26342829/6162307)?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that's a great answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the source you have shared doesn't contain the same line as your error logged.  It has now changed to: `dag = self.get_dag(store_serialized_dags); if dag is None: raise DagNotFound("Dag id {} not found".format(self.dag_id)); subdags = dag.subdags`.  So there is a `NoneType` check now.  If I had to guess, the source itself probably relied on some reference being created, but because your function doesn't do anything with `dag` it interfered with the process somehow.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The answer you referred to doesn't provide any new insight to my case I think.  If I missed any, please point it out to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your do_something_without_passing_dag() is not supposed to know that DAG(**some_parameters) should be passed in its param "dag".

For instance, this works:

```
dag=DAG(**some_parameters)
with dag:
   do_something_without_passing_dag()
```

Comment: Right, it's not supposed to, but somehow it behaves differently with and without the existing variable.  For instance, if I insert `del dag` between the `with` and the `do_something...` line, it doesn't work anymore.  This effect is still not completely understood.

Comment: After the "with dag:" the variable "dag" is defined and as your do_somethin() is probably an airflow operator, which necessarily inherits from BaseOperator, which itself initialize with the parameter "dag" and apply the @apply_defaults decorator. This apply_defaults will look for the predefined variables and apply them as parameters. Therefore if your the dag parameter of do_something_without() is not defined the apply_default will look into existing variable with the same name to fill it in. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think that might be the reason:   Some magic concerning this decorator.  I'm just very surprised that it is supposed to search for `dag` variables in outer stack frames.  I thought it only searches for the contexts in this internal data structure I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes agree, it is not completely obvious. I think the magic happens here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6cbedf8775df77c623f5ca5cace24ed4eecd6a5b/airflow/utils/decorators.py#L55
and here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/abc045b37107819940bbe95b394a5e5dcbd1b513/airflow/models/dag.py#L347-L354